# How best to manage CLLocationManager, MKMapView and placemarks

Tags: ios, authentication, facebook-login, launch

I have the following code, which is used in my `Login.m` view controller class to bypass that screen if the user is already logged in (and linked to Facebook).

For context, I am using Parse Platform, hence the references to `PFUser` class.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // Check if user is cached and linked to Facebook, if so, bypass login
    if ([PFUser currentUser] && [PFFacebookUtils isLinkedWithUser:[PFUser currentUser]]) {
        UITabBarController *tabController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"initialtabview"];
        [self presentViewController:tabController animated:NO completion:^(void){}];
    }
}
```

This certainly works, although the user gets a flash of the Login view before the `initialtabview` appears.

Is there any way I can avoid this?

Note that my app is currently setup such that the Login view is the initial view controller. Therefore perhaps there is something I can do in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in `AppDelegate`?

Note that this code fails completely if used in `viewWillAppear`.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two possible ways to solve your problem:
1. You could try the block of code in the `viewDidLoad:` method, which is called earlier than `viewDidAppear:`.
2. You could start the app with the `InitialTableView` and only load up the `Login.m` view if the user is not cached or linked to Facebook. Then in the `InitialTableView` I would prefer the `viewDidLoad:` function for presenting the login view.